# Outlook.com REST API

Tags: rest, uwp, outlook-restapi

I am making an UWP app somewhat like [Cortanium](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/store/p/cortanium/9nblggh6287g) in which i want to get the mails of the current user's account. For that i have chosen the REST API from outlook.com. But the problem is i don't know from where can i get started. I want to get the user's e-mails and then read it to the user.

I have seen the [article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/api/mail-rest-operations) which shows the API calls that can be made and tried but i am getting this error:

> {"error":{"code":"OAuthMissingForThisAccount","message":"Authentication for this account must be using OAuth."}}

So what do i have to do in order to get a proper response ?

(P.S:I am new in the REST API world so correct me if i am wrong anywhere)

Comment: In waht programming language do you want to implement it?

Answer (score 1):

From your error info, I think it's possible that you didn't handle the user authorization.

For every request to the Mail API, a valid access token is needed. To get this access token, you can refer to [Register and authenticate your app](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/api/use-outlook-rest-api#register-and-authenticate-your-app).

In this doc:

> To use the Outlook REST API to access a user's mailbox data, your app should handle registration and user authorization:
>
> 1. First, register your app to get access to the Outlook REST API. You can then implement the API calls in your app.
> 2. At runtime, get authorization from the user and make REST API requests to access the user's mailbox.